# how does one test javascript interactions such as drawing with mouse in html5 canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, tdd, jasmine

I'm familiar with testing objects states such as with rspec in ruby on rails models.  For example: This object should meet this expectation given this prior state and receiving this call.

But what if I want to do some TDD on a jquery plugin for painting lines in an html5 canvas?  How can I test this?  Given that a user has clicked on the canvas and moved the pointer, then there should be a line drawn on the canvas.  It's not like I can simulate user activity like that using jasmine right?  Is this something that is outside of the scope of TDD and can only do manual testing for?

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to know where to stop with testing, what you should be testing and how.
In general when I have to deal with interfacing with something I consider external to what I am developing, a library, a network service, an ajax call, an external server, a canvas in your case I will start thinking about how to **mock** it.

I am not very familiar with the canvas. I would go about it in either of these ways:

1) If you only want to make sure that your code does something to the canvas it is simple to use spies directly on it. Spies are very powerful tools, learn about them and use them. For instance, if you wanted to make sure that the canvas path is updated you could do

```
var spy = spyOn(canvas, 'moveTo').andCallFake(function (x, y) {
  expect(x).toEqual(10.0);
  expect(y).toEqual(20.0);
});

//Do something through your api that would call canvas.moveTo
...
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Of course, you could have spied on any of the other canvas methods.

2) If you need tests that do a whole lot of interactions and/or you find yourself writing the same spies again and again for different tests, it might be the case that you will be better off with a mock object. Be careful: Don't rewrite the library you are mocking! Keep it simple and mock only the things you need, adding as you go. Also, have a look at the available mocking libs that might help you out, or give you ideas. Lots of jasmine people are using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/). Personally I stick with bare jasmine and rely on my own mocks when I need them.

Right, so let me try to come up with something ;) For a canvas I would expect that a mocking object would have say the essential methods you need, `beginPath`, `moveTo`, `stroke`, whatever... You could make it so that instead of drawing to a canvas, they append points to an array representing your path. Then your test would become a number of interactions with your code and at the end you could get the path from your mock and provide expectations on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can and should simulate user activity by having some functions or state that gets called every time the mouse or touch events are called. This canonicalization of input lets you simulate input very easily.

For example you could write a canvas app that draws a line from mouse-down to mouse-up. We could write it like this:

var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

```
can.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    var mouse = getMouse(e, can);
    doMouseDown(ctx, mouse.x, mouse.y);
}, false);

can.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    var mouse = getMouse(e, can);
    doMouseUp(ctx, mouse.x, mouse.y);
}, false);


function doMouseDown(ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
}

function doMouseUp(ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Now if you wanted to simulate a user putting their mouse down somewhere and up somewhere else all you have to write is this:

```
// simulate the mouse doing these actions!
doMouseDown(ctx, 50, 50);
doMouseUp(ctx, 200, 120);​
```

Easy enough!

This isn't the most brilliant way to go about this sort of thing but it gives you the idea. I'd make a sort of state object/class for each canvas but thats just a matter of organization.

Testing then becomes easy because anything a user does with a mouse or touchpad you are able to do in code to test. In fact, both your mouse-down code and touch-start code can now be considered equivalent to your app since they will both simply call doMouseDown/Up. As a matter of principle its always good to separate the doing logic from the raw input.

Here's the full working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/CU72J/

Comment: Well I get that I can directly trigger the methods that would otherwise be triggered by the actual event handlers, but if there was a rendering bug (say the stroke color is white and background is also white, or opacity is transparent), there would be no logical error in the code, yet my expectation that "I should see a line" can only be observed with my own eyes right?  I can't make an assertion of the correct out come in code, can i?

Comment: if you want to literally check a location for some color you can use the canvas' `getImageData` and look through the pixels for a white (or very close to white) pixel at a given location.